Reprint classic text editions in bibliography
I have asked the question also here: https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=25564
I have the following problem: In some places I quote ancient texts whose edition is a reprint ("Ndr."). When I cite the ancient text and the text edition, "Ndr..." is also displayed in the bibliography. But if I cite the ancient text in my edition without the edition, only the older edition appears in the bibliography (i.e. "Ndr. ..." is missing); how can I ensure that the reprint is also given in the latter case?
Here is my MWE:
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=separate,backend=biber,sblfootnotes=false,ibidpage=true,ibidtracker=true,idemtracker=true,pagetracker=spread,sorting=nyvt,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex} 


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Procop,
 title = {Procopius Caesariensis. Opera omnia},
editor = {Haury, J. and Wirth, G.},
series = {BSGRT},
address = {Leipzig},
year = {1962},
endyear = {1964},
keywords = {sekundaer},
volumes = {4},
 gender = {pm},
related = {Proc.2001.2},
relatedtype = {reprint},
edition = {2},
}
@book{Proc.2001.2,
 location = {München and Leipzig},
 date = {2001},
}
@book{Prokop,
author = {{Procop. Aed.}},
entrysubtype = {classical}, Options = {skipbib=true}, Options = {skipbiblist=true}, xref = {Procop},
shorthand    = {{Procop. Aed.}},
}

@book{Evagr.FC.HE,
shorttitle = {Ecclesiastical History of Evagrius},
title = {The Ecclesiastical History of Evagrius with the Scholia. Edited with introduction, critical notes, and indices},
editor = {Bidez, J. and Parmentier, L.},
year = {1898},
location = {London},
keywords = {sekundaer},
 gender = {pm},
related = {Evagr.FC.HEX},
 relatedtype = {reprint},
}
@book{Evagr.FC.HEX,
date={1964},
location = {Amsterdam},
}
@book{Evagr.HE,
author = {{Evagr. h. e.}},
entrysubtype = {classical}, Options = {skipbib=true}, Options = {skipbiblist=true}, xref = {Evagr.FC.HE},
shorthand    = {{Evagr. h. e.}},
}% number = {57,1–2},

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Hier wird der antiken mit dem Neudruck angegeben.\footnote{Vgl. \cite[5]{Evagr.HE}. Textausgabe des Neudrucks: \cite[10]{Evagr.FC.HE}.}

Hier wird nur der antike Text zitiert.\footnote{\cite[Vgl.][1]{Prokop}.}
\printbibliography
\end{document}


You can see that the citation of Bidez/Parmentier works well, but the information of reprint of Haury and Wirth is missing. It should be:

Haury, J., und G. Wirth, Hrsg.Procopius Caesariensis. Opera omnia. 2. Aufl. 4 Bde.BSGRT. Leipzig, 1962–1964.  Ndr., München und Leipzig, 1964.


Hi, can you please include a screenshot? Thank you

I think the solution can be the addendum field. Thus, I need some modifications and ask a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/716041/remove-punctuation-before-addendum

Well it is clearly more or less by design. The bib-macro related tests if the entry has been cited and the value is hard coded. You could make a feature request for biblatex to support your use case.
A work around is to cite the entry with \nocite{Procop}. You can even do that inside the entry itself (the comment of David explains why only the location München is mentioned):
@book{Prokop,
author = {{Procop. Aed.}},
entrysubtype = {classical}, 
Options = {skipbib=true}, Options = {skipbiblist=true}, 
xref = {Procop},
shorthand    = {{Procop. Aed.}},
execute={\nocite{Procop}}
}

Be aware that this requires two (!) cycles with pdflatex+biber+pdflatex until it picks that up.


The reason only München is mentioned is by design. SBL interleaves location and publisher when there are more than one (e.g., Lund:
Gleerup; Copenhagen: Munksgaard) . This is fine if you have the same number of publishers as locations, but can become ambiguous if there isn't. You can have more publishers than locations, but not more locations than publishers. This is because SBL states that only the first location should be mentioned for a given publisher. So you only ever need two locations if you have two publishers. I think…

@DavidPurton ah, thanks for the feedback.

Another workaround for this issue is to make use of the origlocation and origdate fields. This avoids the related mechanism altogether, but only allows for simple reprint details to be included.
Note that for two locations or origlocations to be printed you must also have two publishers or origpublishers. This is because SBL specifies that only one location should be included per publisher. If you wanted to force two appearing you would need to put München and Leipzig in braces, i.e., location = {{München und Leipzig}}.
If I knew what I was doing (which I don't) I'd probably also use @classictext for Prokup which (in theory) behaves more sanely for ancient works and also allows for primary sources to be included in a more SBL-like list of abbreviations. You don't have to do things this way, of course. (Disclaimer on this: I'm not really familiar with ancient sources, so just trying to follow the SBL Handbook to the best of my ability. They don't list works by Procupius to compare exactly what they want. I couldn't see examples of where they have abbreviated the author and to be honest their rules as to whether titles are emphasised or left as Roman are opaque to me—seems like it often depends on whether a work is well known or has historically been cited in a certain way. One day I'll get my second completely rewritten version of biblatex-sbl finished which already has much better support for ancient works.)
Anyway, the entry for Procop in the MWE below will work as is if you drop it into your example in the question.
MWE
(Sorry, don't know German strings.)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman, provide=*]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl, sblfootnotes=false]{biblatex} 
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{Procop,
  title = {Procopius Caesariensis. Opera omnia},
  editor = {Haury, J. and Wirth, G.},
  series = {Bibliotheca Scriptorum Graecorum et Romanorum Teubneriana},
  shortseries = {BSGRT},
  volumes = {4},
  edition = {2},
  location = {{München und Leipzig}},
  date = {2001},
  origlocation = {Leipzig},
  origdate = {1962/1964}
}
@classictext{Prokop,
  author = {Procopius},
  title = {De Aedificiis},
  shorttitle = {Aed\adddot},
  xref = {Procop},
  keywords = {primary}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Hier wird nur der antike Text zitiert \autocite[\bibcpstring{confer}][1]{Prokop}.
\printbibliography
\printbibheading[title=Abbreviations]
\printbiblist[heading=subbibliography, title=Primary Sources,
  keyword=primary]{abbreviations}
\printbiblist[heading=subbibliography, title=Secondary Sources,
  notkeyword=primary]{abbreviations}
\end{document}


